# Series with a logarithm

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to solve this example (I have to tell if it's convergent or not)

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln{\left(\frac{n^3+n+1}{n^3-n}\right)}$$

I tried to do this by comparison:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln{\left(\frac{n^3+n+1}{n^3-n}\right)} < \frac{1}{n^2}$$
But I'm stuck at this point, I can't tell if it's true. Can you give me any tips? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is true, indeed by $\log(1+x)<x$ as $x>0$ we have that

$$\ln{\left(\frac{n^3+n+1}{n^3-n}\right)}=\ln{\left(\frac{n^3-n+2n+1}{n^3-n}\right)}=\ln\left(1+\frac{2n+1}{n^3-n}\right)<\frac{2n+1}{n^3-n}\sim \frac{2}{n^2}$$

then refer to limit comparison test.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you also tell me if Dirichlet's test can be used for proving divergence? Or it works only one way?

For example if I multiply this logarithm by 5^n, can I use Dirichlet's test to prove the divergence?

Comment: @iforgotmypass Here we are using that both [direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) that is $$\ln\left(1+\frac{2n+1}{n^3-n}\right)<\frac{2n+1}{n^3-n} \implies \sum \ln\left(1+\frac{2n+1}{n^3-n}\right)<\sum \frac{2n+1}{n^3-n}$$ and [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) that is $$\frac{\frac{2n+1}{n^3-n}}{\frac{2}{n^2}}\to 1$$

Comment: I see, but it won't work when I will multiply it by (-5)^n, am I right? Then we have to prove that the partial sums aren't limited?

Comment: @iforgotmypass Yes of course we can also use that for a divergent case. What about for example $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln{\left(\frac{n^3+n^2+1}{n^3-n}\right)}$$ Here we can use limit comaprison test.

Comment: @iforgotmypass For $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln{\left(\frac{n^3+n+1}{n^3-n}\right)}$$ we can use absolute convergence and for $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-5)^n\ln{\left(\frac{n^3+n+1}{n^3-n}\right)}$$ just check that $$(-5)^n\ln{\left(\frac{n^3+n+1}{n^3-n}\right)}\not \to 0$$

Comment: I see now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @iforgotmypass You are welcome! Bye